# Abbreviation: single words in plural

Tags: abbreviations

In my specific case I want to abbreviate the word *section*. I abbreviate the singular case to *sec.* and hope that's correct. I have no idea, however, how to abbreviate *sections*.

Is it *secs*? Is it *sec.s*? Or is it *secs.*?

The same goes for words such as *chapter*.

I couldn't find the answer on this site. I did find about abbreviations with mutliple words (e.g. PhDs). I found answers on specific time units (e.g. hours is hrs) but I don't know if this is the case for my question with any noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviation#Plural_forms) has the following to say on this.

To indicate the plural of the abbreviation or symbol of a unit of measure, the same form is used as in the singular.

1 lb or 20 lb
1 ft or 16 ft
1 min or 45 min

---

For abbreviations of literary terms such as pages, chapters etc. you use the same letter twice: p for page becomes pp for pages; c for chapter becomes cc for chapters; s for section becomes ss for sections.

The problem with using "secs" in this case is that rather than being an abbreviation for sections it's likely to be confused for one meaning seconds. I don't think it's common to abbreviate those terms like that, so I'm not aware of any hard-and-fast rules for it.

Comment: Alternatively, [as Wikipedia points out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_legal_abbreviations#S) use **§§** instead of **ss** for "sections". That's the form I'm used to.

Comment: And I wouldn't use cc for chapters (rather than cubic centimetres). Use ch: *See ch. 5-7.*

Comment: Both good points. I was honestly contemplating deleting my answer entirely as, upon reflection, I wasn't sure any more that it adequately addressed the question being asked, but it got upvoted so I put it back in.

Answer (score 1):

> In my specific case I want to abbreviate the word section. I abbreviate the singular case to sec. and hope that's correct. I have no idea, however, how to abbreviate sections.
>
> Is it secs? Is it sec.s? Or is it secs.?

I think it would be more elegant to just use [the section sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign):

- §: one section;
- §§: multiple sections.